# How to control json data nodejs

Tags: node.js, json

im making a bot to get the price of the peso argentino. Im using a Api but im having some problems to get only the sell price.

```
if (command == "peso"){
    request('https://www.dolarsi.com/api/api.php?type=valoresprincipales', (err, res, body) => {
    
        const data = JSON.parse(body);
        message.channel.send(body);
});
```

Im getting this output:
[image]

And I need to get only this price:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure the API doesn't allow to get only the sell price, do you know all the API routes ?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to get that particular sell price, you must be particular on what property you want to compare to get that sort of data.

Example:

```
const data = JSON.parse(body);

const item = data
   .find(({ casa: { venta } }) => venta === "161,000")
   .casa
   .venta;
```

Attach is the **[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ts-array-object?devtoolsheight=33&file=index.ts)** for your reference with the mock data in reference to your screenshot above